# UITextField with Rounded Corner Without using background images

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

I Want to round the UITextField Corners, to display it something like this

[image: rounded textfield]

i want to do this programatically, not by using images.

Comment: The technique used to round the corners of UIView, doesn't it work? (import QuartzCore and set view.layer.cornerRadius)

Comment: @ranReloaded the answer is working for me.

Comment: Great. didn't have time to check myself.

Comment: You should accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: @BK i will definitely accept the answer, but due to connection error i am unable to do that, i am trying for the same dude. :)

Comment: :) cool, dint mean to be "that" guy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set the Corner-Radius on any UIView-Subclass.

1. Add the **QuartzCore** framework to your project
2. Add `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your `UIViewController` Subclass (where you have access to the `UITextfield` instance of your choice
3. Within **viewDidLoad** / **viewWillAppear** (or any other place where your UITextfield is allready instantiated call `[yourTextField.layer setCornerRadius:14.0f];`
4. Play around with the cornerRadius value until it looks good

I think this will help you.

Comment: How is this an answer?  You can get the rounded ends but the inner shadow is completely messed up.